# How to refactor package import in intelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14

I am plaaning to upgrade joda DateTime api to Java DateTime API in all my classes.

```
import org.joda.time.LocalDate
```

to

```
 import java.time.LocalDate
```

Is there any way to easily perform this refactoring in intellij so that it will resolve and replaces all usages correctly.

Comment: The java 8 time API is not a direct replacement for joda time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, because jodaTime has a different API than the new one from Java 8. IntelliJ has quite good refactoring capabilities, but it can't analyze your application logic and convert method calls from package `A` to different calls - with other parameters - from package `B`.

Of course, you can perform a simple "search + replace". After this, you'll get compiler errors, and you have to correct them manually.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to have a look at the `Type Migration` refactoring feature.

Place the cursor onto the type you want to be replaced and hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>.

This is not doing the replacement for the whole project at once but it may help you.